# Googlemap Api V3 Catch event

Tags: events, google-maps-api-3

How do I catch if map type was changed?

- catch if maptype id = roadmap/satellite/hybrid/terrain
- catch if streetview was used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these are pretty straightforward - you simply listen to the proper events:

**Map Type Changed:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function() {
  console.log("map type changed");
});
```

**Streetview Activated:**

```
var pano = map.getStreetView();
google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'visible_changed', function() {
  if (pano.getVisible()) {
    console.log("street view visible");
  }
});
```